# How to install talib in python 3.11, the operating system is Windows 11 64-bit

Tags: python

After installing Anaconda with python 3.11, run conda install ta-lib, the installation is successful, then import talib, return:

```
>>> import talib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'
>>>
```

How to deal with it?

Ability to successfully install talib

Comment: How do you run this code?  What exact command do you use?

Comment: "After installing Anaconda with python 3.11" - are there any other versions of Python on the system? "run conda install ta-lib" What does this mean? exactly what did you type, and where? "the installation is successful" - how do you know? what did you see in the terminal? "then import talib" from where? Did you make sure that you are using the same Python for which you installed the library? Do you know that `talib` is the name that you should `import`? How do you know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- ta-lib is not available for py3.11 on conda-forge channel, ...yet
  (the tests are failing since months)
- so use ta-lib for py3.10 instead, as I do
- also needed to work with ta-lib is the (c-lib) libta-lib: conda install libta-lib